# Redis get Key from Value

Tags: redis, key-value, nosql

ID is unique and i am using it as a key, and the remaining as Hash Value in Redis Databank. I am looking for a query that returns me list of IDs if i give a specific city name. For example if i ask, give me all the IDs of City named SPRINGFIELD it should return me  01103 and 01104.

---

```
{
  "_id": "01103",
  "city": "SPRINGFIELD",
  "loc": [
    -72.588735,
    42.1029
  ],
  "pop": 2323,
  "state": "MA"
}
```

---

```
{
  "_id": "01104",
  "city": "SPRINGFIELD",
  "loc": [
    -72.577769,
    42.128848
  ],
  "pop": 22115,
  "state": "MA"
}
```

---

```
{
  "_id": "01106",
  "city": "LONGMEADOW",
  "loc": [
    -72.5676,
    42.050658
  ],
  "pop": 15688,
  "state": "MA"
}
```

---

Comment: Does my answer help? If yes can you please accept it or if you're still confused I could provide more depth

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify what key you are using in Redis to map to the hash structure for a city, so I am going to assume you use ID since you have said it's unique.

To query for the cities the match a specific name, you will need to build and maintain a secondary indexing structure that supports the query.  One way you can do this use the `SET` data structure and use the city name as a key which points to the set of id's that share that city name.

Answer (score 3):

Redis doesn't support querying data out of the box. It is basically a simple key value store where the values are data structures like Lists, Hashtables e.t.c.

The workaround would be to create a separate list or hashtable of IDs and store that in the Redis. You'll need to maintain the list of any new IDs being added or removed.

If querying is of utmost importance then its probably better for you turn to a [distributed cache](http://blogs.alachisoft.com/ncache/key-value-store-vs-distributed-cache/) like [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) or other caching products which support [querying your data](http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/articles/object-query-language-dist-cache.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is way by which we can achieve this, the concept if indexing. Indexing can be used in a way which will help you achieve this

```
  ZADD myindex 25 Manuel
  ZADD myindex 18 Anna
  ZADD myindex 35 Jon
  ZADD myindex 67 Helen
```

In order to retrieve all persons with an age between 20 and 40, the following command can be used:

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE myindex 20 40
1) "Manuel"
2) "Jon"
```

If you want to know more use this official documentation https://redis.io/topics/indexes

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [RediSearch](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/index.html) was designed to do.

Comment: It'd help if you added some example code or a relevant link to the documentation describing this.